# What does it mean to divide by a pdf

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, conditional-probability, marginal-probability

We know the formula, f(A|B) = f(A,B)/f(B). In my mind the left hand side makes sense since we are basically taking a 2D distribution to a 1D distribution(well it does not necessarily integrate to one but you get the point) by just limiting the value that one of the axes can take.

Interlude; if we integrate only f(A|B) this then gives us P(A|B) right?

f(B) is the marginal density of B, which I understand to be: A takes on all the values and we are just summing f(A,B) for all values of A, such that a new pdf is formed which integrates to 1, this also is 1D. So for example if we have variance decreasing as A gets larger in f(A,B) then f(B) will have a lower variance than f(B|A=minimum(A))

And f(A,B) is then just the 2D probability density.

I think I am just not so clear on what exactly happens when you divide a 2D function by a 1D function and therefore I cannot visualise it.

Comment: This is hard to follow. What is your question?

Comment: It is not clear whether this is about events (they do not have a density)  or random variables, and if the latter whether $B$ takes a particular value so $f_{A \mid B=b}(a \mid B=b)$ or not; if so, you would want $\int_{a=-\infty}^\infty f_{A \mid B=b}(a \mid B=b)  \, da =1$.  Your "So for example if we ..." assertion looks wrong

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I just don't understand what happens when we divide the joint pdf f(A,B) by a marginal PDF. How this would look visually.

Comment: @Henry This is about a joint PDF of two Random variables and I use the notation f(A|B) to imply f(A|B=b). I am not sure why my assertion would be wrong, I would think that if you add 1D normal "looking" functions (not necessarily integrating to 1) each with decreasing variance, to create a new pdf with lower variance than the single function(not necessarily integrating to 1) with maximum variance.

Comment: @LeonVonMoltke Well how the conditional pdf looks graphically depends on the joint distribution. The essential feature is that the conditional pdf, like any density, will integrate to $1$, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y|x)dy=1\quad \forall x.$ Does this [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions) help?